# Optimising sum of 2 from an array - leetcode challenge

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

I was for the first time doing a challenge on the [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/), and I have come up with the JS code for finding the indexes of 2 numbers that add up to a target value that looks like this:

```
let nums = [-3, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0]; 
let target = 0;

var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let checkedNums = [];
    let result = [];
    nums.forEach((num, i) => {
        if (result.length === 0) {
            if (checkedNums.includes(target - num)) {
                result = [nums.indexOf(target - num), i];
            } else {
                    checkedNums.push(num);
            }
        }
    })
    return result;
};

twoSum(mums, target) // outputs [0, 2]
```

But, when I saw that the runtime of this code it `72ms`, and that there are far better runtimes I wonder how can I optimise this code to get a better runtime?
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgn6y7yb/27/).
I have also came up with solution, which I thought would be faster since we stop the for loop immediately when the solution is found, but I didn't see any decrease in the runtime:

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let checkedNums = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (checkedNums.includes(target - nums[i])) {
          return [nums.indexOf(target - nums[i]), i];
        } else {
          checkedNums.push(nums[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the `nums` array consistent with the rules at the description at linked document?

Comment: yes, the nums array is one of the examples I have got as a test array

Comment: Your main problem is performing repeated array searches via `checkedNums.includes` within the inner loop (linear time). Use a `Map` instead. Looking up elements within a `Map` is much faster (constant time on average). You can also get rid of the final `nums.indexOf` by storing checked numbers together with their indices - as a mapping number -> index.

Comment: @Leff _"You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution"_ Value of index `1` added to value of index `5` at `nums` array at code at Question is equal to `target`, yes?

Answer (score 2):

### Style

Your code is pretty readable already. But you mix `var` and `let`. I prefer consistent style.

Also, you use a function expression instead of a function declaration - [there are subtle differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), but it's mostly a matter of personal preference. To me, the function declaration seems simpler.

### Runtime complexity

Your main issue is performing full array searches via `checkedNums.includes` (in linear time) within the inner loop. By using an alternative data structure such as a simple object `{}`, a `Set` or a `Map` which complete such lookups much faster (in constant time), your performance will improve drastically for large inputs.

You can also get rid of the final `nums.indexOf` by mapping numbers to their indices. This doesn't improve theoretical runtime complexity, but still improves performance. The same holds for breaking out of the loop early as soon as a solution is found.

### Implementation

```js
// Return indices of first two number summing up to target:
function twoSums(numbers, target) {
  const map = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
   if (map.has(target - numbers[i])) {
      return [map.get(target - numbers[i]), i];
    } else {
      map.set(numbers[i], i);
    }
  }
}

// Example:
console.log(twoSums([-3, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0], 0)); // [0, 2]
```

### Benchmark

Measuring average runtime over 1000 runs for input arrays of different length, we get the following results:

```
length  original [ms]  improved [ms]
   100            2.4            7.2
   500           32.8           37.6
  1000          120.6           71.2
  5000         2703.4          401.2
 10000        11132.5          792.5
 50000       265770.5         3633.5
100000      1052582.0         7776.5
```

While the original implementation performs better for very small inputs, the improved implementation performs much better for longer arrays. This confirms our above runtime complexity analysis.

Plotting the times against the input length clearly shows the quadratic nature of the original runtime complexity vs. the linear runtime complexity of the improved implementation:

[image: runtime complexity comparison]

Comment: This is the best solution. Great formatting and you came with the idea of the map.

Comment: I did a benchmark on this and you are running 10 times slower than the OPs original post, that would be 720ms in comparison going by the OP's time of 72ms

Comment: @Blindman67 I added my benchmark results.

Comment: @le_m you also changed the code to use `Map` rather than use an object as a map which makes all the difference, nice. V8 (if you are using it) has recently added significant performance improvements to `Map` and `Set` making them indispensable as lookups.

Comment: @Blindman67 I just ran the benchmark on Firefox / Ubuntu again with a plain object instead of `Map`, and the plain object is indeed much slower here, too. It is still faster than OP's code for large arrays, though.

Comment: @le_m its not the size of the array but the range, distribution, and rate of positive results in the array that set the performance.  I tested on an even distribution of 10,000 items in the range -1000 to1000 integer and query range of 0-1000 integer on FF/Win using {} and was  slower than OP's but test did favour early exit, as it had a very low fail to find rate. Knowledge of the data (which is unknown in this case) is very important when creating solutions.

Comment: @Blindman67 True - if one fills the array with completely random integers. But according to the spec, there can only be two elements in the whole array which sum up to the target value. If these two element are placed randomly within the array, we will find the solution on average at 2/3 of the total array length. Granted, the example given by OP doesn't follow the spec as pointed out by guest27131422 above. The runtime analysis above is only valid when following the spec tightly.